# colorblind, lookin for help

Tags: css

I have a div with the color #0063dc which is a bluish color.  i have my page designed so that when a div is hovered over it turns color to look like it's a button being depressed.  only problem is, i've been told that my color isn't exactly right looking. the hover color is background-color:#3355ff; any suggestions as to a color that would look more suitable?

thanks

Comment: i can tell the colors are different, but not what looks good.

Comment: Better asked on Stack Exchange UX site: http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Then that's not color blindness.

Comment: Recommending a color to a color-blind person could have been fun. You know, in an evil way. >:-D

Comment: @BoltClock - yes it is. Color blindness does not necessarily mean you can't see colours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always had a soft spot for `#005bcc`